# How do I sort by value from a second level hash, in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, sorting, numbers, ordinal

```
my $hash_ref = {
    one   => { val => 1, name => 'one'  },
    three => { val => 3, name => 'three'},
    two   => { val => 2, name => 'two'  },
};
```

I would like to sort `$hash_ref` such that a foreach would order them by

```
$hash_ref->{$key}->{'val'}

one
two
three
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

`@sorted_list` is an array of references to the sorted hash elements:

```
 @sorted_list = sort { $a->{'val'} <=> $b->{'val'} } values %{$unsorted_hash_ref};
```

You can use it like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $hash_ref = {
    one   => { val => 1, name => 'one' },
    three => { val => 3, name => 'three' },
    two   => { val => 2, name => 'two' },
};

foreach $elem ( sort { $a->{'val'} <=> $b->{'val'} } values %{$hash_ref} ) {
    print "$elem->{'val'} : $elem->{'name'}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1 : one
2 : two
3 : three
```

Comment: Heh. I was so consumed with conducting the sort based on the english numerical text that I didn't notice the 'val' subkey. Nevertheless, Lingua::EN::Words2Nums means that you don't have to have those subkeys at all -- you can do the sort purely on the higher level keys. :)

Comment: I never heard of Lingua! Very interesting though, I will have to take advantage of it sometime!

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables don't have any specific order. However, you can sort the keys in an array and use that to iterate through the hash:

```
my $hash_ref = {
    one => { val => 1, name => 'one'},
    three => { val => 3, name => 'three'},
    two => { val => 2, name => 'two'},
};

use strict;
use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Words2Nums;

foreach my $key (sort { words2nums($a) <=> words2nums($b) } keys %$hash_ref)
{
    # do something with $hash_ref->{$key}
    print "processing key $key.\n";
}
```

You can define anything you like as a sort method; see [perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for more details.  Conversion from ordinal numerical text to arithmetic values is done with [Lingua::EN::Words2Nums](http://search.cpan.org/~joey/Lingua-EN-Words2Nums-0.15/Words2Nums.pm) (it does cardinal numbers too).

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash_ref = (
one   => { val => 1, name => 'one'  },
three => { val => 3, name => 'three'},
two   => { val => 2, name => 'two'  },
);

foreach my $key(sort {$hash_ref{$a}{val} <=> $hash_ref{$b}{val}} keys %hash_ref) {
my $value = $hash_ref{$key}{val};
my $name = $hash_ref{$key}{name};
print "$name -> $value\n";
}

output:
one -> 1
two -> 2
three -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


my $hash_ref = (
                one   => {val => 1,  name => "one"},
                three => {val => 3,  name => "three"},
                two   => {val => 2,  name => 'two'},
               );

foreach $elem( sort {$$hash_ref{$a}{val} <=> $$hash_ref{$b}{val}} keys %$hash_ref){
    my $value = $hash_ref->{$elem}{val};
    my $name = $hash_ref->{$elem}{name};
    print "$name -> $value\n";
}

OutPut:
one -> 1
two -> 2
three -> 3
```